# Color not changing on component using "secondary" when theme changes vuetify

Tags: vue.js, components, themes, vuetify.js

I have set up a button that when clicked, will change the theme. This initially worked fine until I wanted to change the card color to the secondary theme color. Like this:

```
       <v-card
         color="secondary"
       >
```

This works as expected with the current theme, however, when I change the theme using the button, everything else changes except this component. I need this to change to the other theme's secondary color when the theme changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your Vuetify themes globally in Vuetify config object like this:

```
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#3f51b5',
        secondary: '#b0bec5',
        accent: '#8c9eff',
        error: '#b71c1c',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[More info](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. The problem is not with setting the theme itself, that works. The problem is that I have 2 themes (Dark and Light), when I switch from either of those, components using the "secondary" theme color don't change.

Comment: in themes object you can configure all your teams. In my example it's only Light theme, but you can add Dark theme onject as well with specific colors

Comment: The problem is not with setting the theme, that works fine. I have a card that uses the current secondary theme color (or at least that's what I expect), but when the theme is changed to another, existing theme, It doesn't change the color and stays on the old theme's secondary color.

Comment: ah I got you:) well, can you check, maybe both themes have the same secondary color?

Comment: Lol they both had the same secondary color, I'm an idiot. Thanks!